# Hydrogen peroxide decomposition and catalase uses

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes

All google searches have simply returned more info on catalase. I'm looking for a catalyst that isn't found inside living organisms which  can break down H2O2. Looking for any resources to look at, or just examples of other catalysts.

Side question since I don't want to clutter with a new thread.
Can catalase be used for anything other than the decomposition of h2o2?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_peroxide#Decomposition - you're looking for non-biological catalysts so you should ask on Chemistry SE

Comment: @Mithoron yea I suppose, I just received this question in bio class so I thought there might be some relevance.

Answer (score -1):

Manganese(IV)oxide can be used as a catalyst to speed up the decomposition of hydrogen peroxide

Comment: A reference would be appreciated Hamza.